# java generics: accepting an interface in Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have `ClasseA implements I`, how do I do something like:

```
public class Classe<T> {
  void function(Class<T> param) {
    ...
  }
}

Classe<I> c=new Classe();
c.function(ClasseA.class);
```

Since `ClasseA` implements the interface `I`, I would like `function` to accept either a class literal of type `ClasseA` or a class implementing `I`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify constraints on the type this way: `Classe<T extends I>`

Comment: Thanks:  I really intended an answer that wouldn't have me change my definition of `Classe` but I am afraid I wasn't specific enough in my question.

Comment: As I see it y have to change either definition of the class itself or the function definition: void function(Class<? extends I> param) - this way accepted function parameter type doesn't depend on the class Classe definition at all.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
public Class Classe<T extends I> {
  void function(Class<T> param) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial about generics available here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

A possible solution to your problem:

```
public class Snippet {

    static class Classe<T> {
        public void function(Class<? extends T> param) {
            System.out.println(param);
        }
    }

    interface I {
    }

    class ClasseA implements I {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Classe<I> c = new Classe();
        c.function(ClasseA.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like overkill to me: public <X extends Class<? extends T>> void function(X param). You can do the same in a short way: public void function(Class<? extends T> param) - since you don't use X type anywhere else.