# java generics: accepting a class or interface

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have:

```
public class Components<T> extends TupleList<Class<T>, String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void add(Class<T> classe, String name) {
        this.add(new Tuple<Class<T>, String>(classe, name));
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
Components<IFilter> engines=new Components<IFilter>(){{
   add(FilterEngineIdentity.class, "Identity");
}};
```

where `FilterEngineIdentity implements IFilter`.  How would I achieve this without binding my class `Components` to more specific class definitions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java generics: accepting an interface in Class<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891216/java-generics-accepting-an-interface-in-classt)

Comment: no not a duplicate, I wasn't specific enough in my request in the previous question.

Comment: Can you really do this class TupleList<Class<T>, E> {} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: It works! See my test added on the bottom.**

Would the following work?

```
Class<? extends T>
```

Whole class:

```
public class Components<T> extends TupleList<Class<?extends T>, String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void add(Class<? extends T> classe, String name) {
        this.add(new Tuple<Class<? extends T>, String>(classe, name));
    }
}
```

The test (compiles without problems on my machine, Java 1.7 but I didn't use the <> so it should work fine with other versions):

```
public interface Interface {}

public class Test<T>
{
public void add(Class<? extends T> x)
{

}

public static void x()
{
    Test<Interface> t = new Test<Interface>();
    t.add(Implementation.class);
}

public static class Implementation implements Interface{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you're looking for, I think this is more clear and typesafe:

```
public interface Interface {
}

public class Test<T> {

    public <K extends T> void add(Class<K> x) {

    }

    public static void x() {
        Test<Interface> t = new Test<Interface>();
        t.add(Implementation.class);
    }

    public static class Implementation implements Interface {
    }
}
```