# Is it possible to create generic class with Type Parameter as Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to create generic class as following?

```
 public class AnyClassTypeWithValue<Class<T>, E> {
}
```

I read code given in this [java generics: accepting a class or interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891446/java-generics-accepting-a-class-or-interface) link. 
I dont think we can create class with type parameters `class SomeClass<Class<T>, E>`
I have seen `class SomeClass<T, E>` but not something like above.

Comment: Yes i did but got compiler error but Jon's answer worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what you'd *mean* by that. Do you want something like:

```
public class AnyClassTypeWithValue<T extends Class<?>, E>
```

perhaps? You can't make `Class<T>` itself the type parameter any more than you can declare a variable with a name `List<String>`.